# I am having issue executing my postgres database query on docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

`\i
'/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/tables/users.sql'

\i '/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/tables/login.sql'`

the error

> /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/deploy_schemas.sql
>   postgres_1         | psql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/deploy_schemas.sql:3: error: \i: missing required argument

Comment: Could you list your whole docker-entrypoint.sh and your exact commands how you get to this error?

Comment: How do i get docker-entrypoint.sh

Comment: server started
postgres_1         | CREATE DATABASE
postgres_1         |
postgres_1         |
postgres_1         | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/deploy_schemas.sql
postgres_1         | psql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/deploy_schemas.sql:3: error: \i: missing required argument
postgres_1         |
postgres_1         | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization

Comment: Not asking for exact log (although that's useful too), but your user commands - i.e. docker run command.

To list entrypoint - do `docker run --rm --entrypoint /bin/bash your_image cat /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh`.

And if possible please update your question itself, it's hard to read in the comments.

Comment: Or just show us what image you're using: if you're using e.g. the standard `postgres` image, we can look at the docker entrypoint script ourselves. But in any case, you need to provide enough information for us to reproduce the problem.